# Binding and validate Date Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a problem with date properties in Angular. For example, I have the next Model (typescript)

```
export class Model{
dateFrom Date;
dateTo Date;
}
```

In the Create view I have:

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)] = "model.dateFrom">
<input type="date" [(ngModel)] = "model.dateTo">

<button type="button" (click)="save()"></button>
```

And in my typescriptFile I have the next function:

```
public save(){
   if(model.dateFrom > model.dateTo){
          //Show Error!
   }
}
```

Here is the problem: model.dateFrom and model.dateTo are strings! Not Date! 
I need to do many date comparations and then send the data to .net web api.
How do I transform string to date ? Or  How could to do Angular binding return a date type?
How should I do date validations???
In Jquery projects I use moment.js but in Angular project, What do you use for date validations??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't even think your code will compile. What is `dateFrom Date` supposed to mean? Anyway, the `date` input type works with strings of the form `yyyy-mm-dd`. They should compare as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// transform string to date

new Date('2017-08-24 00:00:00');  // true    2017-08-24 00:00:00
new Date('2017-08-24 00:00');     // true    2017-08-24 00:00:00
new Date('2017-08-24 00');        // false   2017-08-24 00:00:00

new Date('2017-08 00:00');        // true    2017-08-01 00:00:00
new Date('2017 00:00');           // true    2017-01-01 00:00:00
```

Angular is use Typescript

Typescript is Javascript transpiler

then Angular is javascript

want you date validations in Angular project?

Use moment.js

Comment: Excellent! Thanks ! How Do you integrated Moment.js in Angular ?? Do you use npm ? Or, Do you download Moment.js (javascript files) and access it manually (as Jquery with declare var jQuery:any;) ?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @yesterday One way I know of is to use npm to add [@types/moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/moment) and there is a way to use `declare var moment: any;`.Both of these methods use npm

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what date format the api is expecting. Javascript date objects are based on a time value that is the number of **milliseconds** since 1 January, 1970 UTC. [[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

I would recommend using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to help you with date parsing, especially if you doing it often. Dealing with dates in javascript like *traversing a maze with booby traps waiting in places you'd never expect*

The library has a straight forward API

```
let dateA = moment('01/01/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
let dateB = moment('01/01/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
// You can perform operations between the variables like so
dateB.diff(dateA, 'years') // returns 1
```

Comment: How Do you integrated Moment.js in Angular ?? Do you use npm ? Or, Do you download Moment.js (javascript files) and access it manually (as Jquery with declare var jQuery:any;) ?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You both ways you mentioned would work, it depends on how your project in use is structured